# How important is the Tallith?

Tags: tallit-gadol

How important is the Tallith ?

Is it to remember mitzvot?
I have heard you pray when it covers your head,why?
Is it only a symbol ?
Is it more then a tradition?

Is your prayers less important without the Tallith?

(Very interested in the Tallith!)

Comment: To make this question answerable, please [edit] in what you know already, how you know it, and what you're curious about. Right now, those points are not clear, so it's impossible for anyone else to make this question answerable and consistent with your intent. You may be interested in checking out [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallit) and/or [this JewFAQ entry](http://www.jewfaq.org/signs.htm#Tzitzit) for general information about *talitot*.

Comment: trying to edit hoping it won't get worse

Answer (score 1):

Numbers 15:37-41, the source in the Torah for tzitzit, or the fringes on the edges of a tallit, does not mention anything about the tallit gadol or prayer shawl because before the destruction of the Second Temple there was no tallit gadol. Instead, the Torah commands that tzitzit must be attached to four cornered garments, which was part of a normal man's wardrobe at the time.

After the destruction of the Second Temple the rabbis in Babylon instituted the wearing of a prayer shawl with tzitzit attached to it during morning prayers to continue the mitzvah of tzitzit, because four cornered garments became a less common mode of dress.

In most Ashkenazic communites, the tallit gadol is not worn by un-married men.

Orthodox Jews today also wear a four cornered garment called a tallit katan with tzitzit attached. Even though the Torah doesn't mention wearing a four cornered garment all the time, we do so anyway and now it is halachah.

The tallit gadol is worn generally worn during morning prayers by married men. It reminds us that Hashem fills the entire earth and surrounds us.

(Note: The Torah states that the purpose of tzitzit is to remind us of the mitzvot.)

Comment: "After the destruction of the Second Temple the rabbis in Babylon instituted the wearing of a prayer shawl with tzitzit attached to it during morning prayers to continue the mitzvah of tzitzit, because four cornered garments became a less common mode of dress." I've never heard of that. Where is this recorded?

Comment: But the fringes are the to remember mitzvot? And you have it over your head while you pray? Like you pray inside it,it covers you,why?

Comment: @Eagle - If you read Psalm 104:1-2, it says "ברכי נפשי את -ה' ה' אלקי גדלת מאד הוד והדר לבשת עוטה אור כשלמה נוטה שמים כיריעה." "My soul bless Hashem; Hashem my G-d, You are greatly exalted; with beauty and splendor are you clothed. Enwrapped in light, garment like, He spreads out the heavens like a curtain." These verses are part of the prayer before putting on the tallit gadol, actually. It shows us that the tallit is likened to Hashem enwrapping us and surrounding us in everything we do.

Comment: @EzraHoerster interesting

Comment: How far back is this combination do you think,this psalm and putting on the tallit gadol?

Comment: @Eagle - I would assume ever since the tallit gadol was invented, but I'm not sure. Obviously not from Har Sinai because Psalm 104 wasn't written then!